# How do I overwrite the @timestamp field with another field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I incorrectly ingested lots of documents into Elasticsearch using the wrong `@timestamp` field. I already changed the affected Logstash pipeline to use the correct timestamps, but I cannot re-ingest the old data.

I do however have another document field that can be used as the timestamp (`json.created_at`). So I'd like to update the field. I've found that I can use [the `_update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) action to do that, but I've tried several versions that didn't work, including this:

```
POST logstash-rails_models-*/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source.@timestamp = ctx._source.json.created_at"
  }
}
```

This complains about an unexpected character:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "compile error",
        "script_stack": [
          "ctx._source.@timestamp = ctx._source. ...",
          "            ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "ctx._source.@timestamp = ctx._source.json.created_at",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "compile error",
    "script_stack": [
      "ctx._source.@timestamp = ctx._source. ...",
      "            ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "ctx._source.@timestamp = ctx._source.json.created_at",
    "lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "unexpected character [@].",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "lexer_no_viable_alt_exception",
        "reason": null
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to access this field is via brackets and wrapped in quotes:

```
POST logstash-rails_models-*/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._source['@timestamp'] = ctx._source.json.created_at"
  }
}
```

See also [this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-timestamp-in-a-update-by-query/109581/3) and some more info about [updating fields with Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html#_updating_fields_with_painless).